# How to remove virtual environment for Python in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For example , my virtual env call "venv" .

Can I remove the virtual env by just remove the "venv" folder that create by python3 -m venv .venv ? is there any other command need to type?

I delete the folder with env already before I create a new folder and env with the same name, how can I check the old one is already gone?

I am not using anaconda to create env . I am using vscode (MACOS) .https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_start-vs-code-in-a-project-workspace-folder

thanks.

Comment: I delete the folder with env already before I create a new folder and env with the same name, how can I check the old one is already gone?

Comment: In linux type: ls 
In windows type: dir 

In terminal / cmd

Comment: sorry ,forget to mention that I am in macos

Comment: Just use the linux one. Mac is a Unix operating system

Comment: I recover the folder from rubbish bin. And when I type ls , it show nothing in that dir. but when I open it with vs code , the "venv" folder still there.

Comment: So I should follow the link you suggest and try the answer that with "76" upvote?

Comment: Try every answer until your problem is fixed. In stackoverflow the answer with green tick only indicates that the person who asked the question has chosen that particular answer because it worked for him.If it doesn’t work for you, try different one. Also when asking a question please search a bit on here (Stackoverflow)